# How to set onblur and onfocus string for placeholder when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, append

I have tried to update my html dynamically and it is working so far that the textarea is being added to the page but the onblur and onfocus behaviour that I have defined aren't due I think to the inclusion of double quotations on the onblur and onfocus properties. My code is as follows:

```
$('#answerList').append('<li><div class="row"><div class="eight columns"><textarea id="answerText" name="answerText" placeholder="Your answer here..."  onfocus="this.placeholder = """ onblur="this.placeholder = "Your answer here...""></textarea></div><div class="four columns"><input type="checkbox" name="correctCheckbox" id="correctAnswerCheckbox' + answerPosition + '" value="' + answerPosition + '"/><label for="correctAnswerCheckbox' + answerPosition + '">Correct Answer</label></div></div></li>');
```

When just coding the HTML normally I use the following:

```
<textarea id="questionText" name="questionText" placeholder="Your question here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your question here...'"></textarea>
```

How can I fix the javascript so these properties work

Comment: `placeholder` attribute does the same as you are defining. On focus, its value gets null and on blur, its value gets back to the same.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the placeholder on focus and blur? The placeholder attribute should already take care of toggling the text on focus and blur.

Comment: Yes I know its more to do string formation really, I was using single quotations for the string when typing html but when doing append this is causing issues

Comment: Its a bug in IE10 works in all other browsers for textarea, workaround just for this

Comment: what exactly was your objective? because as Barry mentioned, those are handled by html5 itself

Comment: to clear placeholder on textarea on focus in IE10, as this is not working by default its a bug

Answer (score 2):

""(Doubles quotes) cant escape the ''(Single Quotes). but where as the single Quotes can escape the double quotes.

In your case, i guess if you still need to want to escape single quote specified inside double quote then use a backward slash ().

```
<textarea id="questionText" name="questionText" placeholder="Your question here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = \'\'" onblur="this.placeholder =\ 'Your question here...\'"></textarea>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks this resolved the compiler issues but still was not able to append the textarea as intended with the specified placeholder and behaviour onfocus and onblur

Comment: Can you just check this as the "Answer" then,so that this question can be closed from SO, it will reduce the number of Open Questions from SO :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem this string might help you.

```
'<textarea id="questionText" name="questionText" placeholder="Your question here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = \'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = Your question here..."></textarea>'
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aD38E/

Comment: I have still been unable to get the onfocus and onblur to work when I am appending the html dynamically, my string is in the correct format in the html I guess im still going wrong with my quotations I am using \' for start and end of onfocus and onblur text

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the inclusion of consecutive double-quotes is the issue.  The simple fix is to escape the double-quotes with a backslash, like so:

```
onfocus="this.placeholder = \"\""
```

or

```
onblur="this.placeholder = \"Your answer here...\""
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud36Y/

Comment: Also, here is a Fiddle showing your functionality in a more jQuery-friendly manner.  This method of writing jQuery resolves your multiple, nested quotes issue as well.
http://jsfiddle.net/XZc4f/5/

Comment: This seems to work for me in IE10; can you be more specific about what you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'))
        .attr('placeholder', '');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
});

// $('textarea') or $('input[type="email"]')
```